# Opening a csv file using SPSS

Tags: csv, spss

I'm trying to load my csv file to spss. But it is unable to load while I'm getting this error. Can someone please help me to identify what the error is.

```
GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT 
  /FILE="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Msc-2016\BI-Application\Crimes\train1.csv" 
  /ENCODING='Locale' 
  /DELCASE=LINE 
  /DELIMITERS="," 
  /QUALIFIER='"' 
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED 
  /FIRSTCASE=1 
  /IMPORTCASE=ALL 
  /VARIABLES= 
  V1 A14 
  V2 A8 
  V3 F1.0 
  V4 A4 
  V5 A5 
  V6 A4 
  V7 A5 
  V8 A9 
  V9 A22 
  V10 A53 
  V11 A10 
  V12 A17 
  V13 A29 
  V14 A12 
  V15 A11.
```

> Error.  Command name: GET DATA
> (2269) Failure opening file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\Msc-2016\BI-            Application\Crimes\train1.csv
> Execution of this command stops.  CACHE.  EXECUTE.

> Error # 105.  Command name: EXECUTE
> This command is not valid before a working file has been defined.
> Execution of this command stops.  DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.

Answer (score 3):

From the error message formatting it looks like there might be a nonprinting special character such as a tab in the name after BI-.  Or perhaps the file is in use by another process.  Have you tried using Read Text Data menu wizard to select the file?

Answer (score 1):

use shift+right click on the file name in the folder, select "copy as path", then paste in the syntax, to make sure you have the full path and name of file.